# How to create a subset from a data.frame by comparing a column with a column from another data.frame?

Tags: r

Data1 is a dataframe of 1 column which has unique numbers (sort of primary keys).

Data2 is a dataframe which has 11 columns. The last column is of unique numbers (primary keys).

I want to create a subset of Data2 with every row which has the same unique numbers(primary keys in column 11) as in Data1. I tried using which function:

```
data2_new <- which(data2[,11]== data1[,1])
```

But this gives an error:

```
Error in Ops.factor: level sets of factors are different.
```

Kindly guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data<-data2[data2$keys==data1$keys,]
```

Altenatively, you can just do a left_join:

```
data<-dplyr::left_join(data1, data2, by="keys")
```

Comment: still it is showing same error - Error in Ops.factor: level sets of factors are different. What might be the reason behind this?

Comment: Sounds like your keys are a factor rather than integer/character. What do you get when you do `class(data2$keys)` (and the same for data1)?

Comment: class(data2$keys) shows as factors. for data1 I can't say because it is dynamically generated when I give input in shiny app. What should I do?

Comment: `data2$keys<-as.character(data2$keys)` (or as.integer if they're numbers). For data1 you can pass it to the function with the as.character

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have data frame #1 (with your primary key)

```
df1 <- data.frame(primary_key = c(1, 3, 5, 6, 8))

> df1
  primary_key
1           1
2           3
3           5
4           6
5           8
```

and

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  col_11 = c(0:9),
  letter = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
  value = c(1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2))
> df2
   col_11 letter value
1       0      A     1
2       1      A     1
3       2      A     3
4       3      A     1
5       4      A     2
6       5      B     1
7       6      B     3
8       7      B     4
9       8      B     5
10      9      B     2
```

You can use the `dplyr::left_join` to 'merge' these data frames together.

```
df2 %>% # the data you want to subset
  semi_join(df1, by = c("col_11" = #the name of your "sort of primary key" column in dataframe2
                          "primary_key")) # the name of your column in dataframe 1

       col_11 letter value
    1      1      A     1
    2      3      A     1
    3      5      B     1
    4      6      B     3
    5      8      B     5
```

If the key names are the same, you can just do.

```
df2 %>% # the data you want to subset
  semi_join(df1, by = "primary_key")
```

The `semi_join` helps subset df2.

Comment: still it is showing same error - Error in Ops.factor: level sets of factors are different. What might be the reason behind this?